What does it mean if a model acts normal on a training set but is abnormal on validation set
I am trying to classify either an image of 25x25 px stacked together as 50x25 px is the same(1) or different(0). I am using keras to create the NN layers. The Keras sequential layers are shown below:
layers.Input((2*imsize,imsize,3)),            # shape of input with 3 channels
layers.Reshape((2,imsize,imsize,3)),          # Turn the input into two 25x25 images
layers.LayerNormalization(axis=[-1,-2,-3]),   # Normalize images
layers.Flatten(),                             # Flatten array
layers.Dense(16,activation='relu'),           # 16 outputs hidden layer
layers.Dense(2,activation='softmax')    

Then I compiled the layers using adam optimiser with loss and accuracy like so:
ml.compile(optimizer='adam',
       loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
       metrics=['accuracy'])

After that, I trained the model using epoch=20 and batch_size=100. I got these as a result after plotting it based on epoch.
Results


Current Evaluation:
My current observation is that

the model is overfitting as it performs normally only on the training set?
the model is learning the wrong things as the loss is increasing instead of decreasing on the validation set

My question is: Is my evaluation of the model correct? How should I understand this results in order to improve it?
Update:
Sample Dataset of same(1):

Sample Dataset of different(0):


It's probably overfitting, it could mean you don't have enough data, have a model that is too complex for the task (probably not the case this time), or a lot of other things.
by the way the model you provided is not a CNN model, if you use one you'll see much better results.

Oh yes that is true, it is just normal NN layers my bad. In this case, I have in the training set:
10,000 images of 0 and 10,000 images of 1.
While there are in the validation set:
2000 images of 0 and 500 images of 1.
Will this imbalance in validation set also cause overfitting?

It is generally good practice to sample the validation set randomly, you can use sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split to generate the train and validation sets. not sure if that would cause overfitting in your case, my guess is that the model just isn't the right fit (again, highly recommend proper CNN models)

It seems like the model is getting overfitted on the training dataset. To fix this you can do a few things:

Add more variety in the training data. All the training images might be too similar, so the model fails at different images. Mix it up. One way to do this is Data Augmentation.

Try simplifying the model. Simplifying the model can also help reduce overfitting.


Also check out this article for more tips on how to prevent overfitting

By simplifying the model, do you mean that I should reduce the number of layers?

@Squish Yeah. Although its hard to tell without knowing what your dataset is.

I've updated the sample of the dataset above. Each image consists of 2 sub-images that produces 1 if it is the same and 0 if it is different. I have in the training set: 10,000 images of 0 and 10,000 images of 1. While there are in the validation set: 2000 images of 0 and 500 images of 1. Does that help?

@Squish Like Dan previously mentioned, you should sample the validation set randomly, instead of using a fixed set.
